# Instantly Update Range Value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, input, range

I have a range, and I want to update the span that displays its numeral value instantly.  The code that I have works, but only displays numeral value when you stop holding the left click down.

Here's what I have:

```
$("#length").change(function(){  // when range is altered, execute function
    len = $("#length").val(); // set variable "len" to the numeral value of range
    $("#password-length").html(len); // set "len" (numeral value) to a span
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9Fbm/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check for both the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) and [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) events to achieve this.

In this case:

```
$("#length").on('input change', function(){
   $("#password-length").html(this.value);
});
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9Fbm/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also change it to mousemove

```
$("#length").mousemove(function(){
        len = $("#length").val();
    $("#password-length").html(len);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but @null's approach works better because it works w/ arrows.